# Stand-alone editor for editing wiki text on Windows/Internet Explorer

Tags: mediawiki

I am looking for stand-alone program that have a good easy editor for creating wiki context and then upload to an internal [MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki) installation.

We have a private MediaWiki. Many users are new to wikis and get confused by the syntax, but want to use it. A little toolbar in the wikipage editor is not good enough. I found MSWord converted here:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Word2MediaWikiPlus

But not good enough. I think a nice stand-alone program with the ability to edit tables and such graphically would be really good. Is there anything like that for Windows?

Everything seem to be for Firefox, but we have to use Internet Explorer internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/), it does a decent job of exporting to Mediawiki format.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_tools#Importing_.28converting.29_content_to_Wikipedia_.28MediaWiki.29_format):

> **OpenOffice 3:** Text documents opened in all versions of OpenOffice.org 3 can be exported natively into MediaWiki format, via the File -> Export -> File Format drop down menu. Since OpenOffice.org can open all Microsoft Office files, one can open files created in Microsoft Word and export them to the MediaWiki format.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use WYSIWYG editor, like [FCK](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FCKeditor_%28Official%29). Incidentally, you can also open this in a separate browser window (which, from your question, you might be looking for).